# Show HTML from HDMI

Tags: raspbian, node.js, jessie-lite

On Raspbian Jessie Lite, is it possible to show HTML pages through HDMI using node and webkit? I am not sure on the internals of the Pi for custom graphics, so this question.

It is however possible to stream videos using omxplayer and show images using `fbi`, so I was wondering is there a similar way to show some graphics as well using HTML/JS to offer somekind of little lightweight media control, without using the full rasbian desktop or OSMC or whatever.

*PS - Good to know of any lib/npm packages which does this.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

You can try nwjs - an open source project integrating NodeJS inside a full Chromium browser (so webkit UI)

You can write all the UI in pure HTML/JS/CSS

Regards

Comment: I highly doubt this will work without a window manager. So I don't think it will work on raspbian-light.